# jquery if - event shortcut exists?

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of condition in the code, where show/hide of elements depends if input value is not empty.

Does exist any shorter version for these lines?

```
if ($("input#x").val())
{
   $("#lbl_y").show();
}
else
{
   $("#lbl_y").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#lbl_y").toggle($("input#x").val());
```

Comment: Thank you. That's it. Isn't that `:empty` match childs or text then not input.value? (I mean other respones

Comment: @Jirka Kopřiva: "Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes)." --- from documentation. So I'm not sure how it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such construction:

```
$("#lbl_y")[$("input#x").val() ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

Comment: What an odd way to do this.  It **does** however work in this case.  I'm not too sure its a good solution because of readability issues.  Future programmers would have to look twice to understand exactly what is going on :)

Comment: @Lix It's just brackets notation, absolutly valid javascript.

Comment: Valid yes - but so is the minified version of jQuery - have you tried to read that recently?

Comment: @Lix Yes, it not so easy ;) I think this construction looks simple.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you could bring this down to one line -

```
($("input#x").val() == ''?  $("#lbl_y").show() :  $("#lbl_y").hide() )
```

I'm using here a ternary operator. In this case it behaves much like a simple conditional statement.  It checks the evaluation of a certain condition and performs one task or another depending on the `true/false` value returned by the statement.

```
(condition ? true : false)
```

Comment: Ternary operator **is not** a shorthand version of `if` control structure

Comment: @zer - I've always understood that it was essentially the same.  But thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @Lix: `if (true) var a = 1; else var b = 2;` - try to rewrite this using ternary operator to see they are different

Comment: @Lix: Just to elaborate, the Ternary Operator is intended for assignments in which each expression is a simple statement without side effects. There is no assignment when using it to decide which method to execute. See documentation for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @fra - Thanks for the link, however it **does** state there that `"The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement."`. I now understand the difference though. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lix: Yes it does say that and it is to be taken within context of assignments. The example demonstrates how a ternary operator can replace an `if...else` when determining the assignment of an expression is awkward to express using an `if...else`. That is the only scenario in which you replace an `if...else` with a ternary operator. If you need to determine a path of execution you would not use a ternary operator as that scenario is not going to assign an expression.

Answer (score 1):

like this ternary operator you mean:

You can use `.is(':empty')` to do empty check!

```
var resultofexpression = conditionasboolean ? truepart: falsepart;
```

in your case:

```
$("input#x").is(':empty') ?   $("#lbl_y").show(); : $("#lbl_y").hide();
```

Comment: try: alert($("input").val(123).is(':empty'))

Comment: Side-Note on ternary operators. Using the ternary operator `? ... :` to execute functions without assignment is not what it is intended for. The operator is intended for assignments in which each expression is a simple statement without side effects. Just as you have shown in the original example. JSLint in jsFiddle will also show a warning: `Problem at line x character x: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` See documentation for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @FrançoisWahl `:)` Wat up bruv! howz life! Thanks for the comment!